# how to get child id and draw svg under it

Tags: javascript, svg, parent-child

I have a group of polygon containing other smaller polygon. I want to draw a triangle under the bottom polygon by using id of child polygon. I don't know how to make it by using child id as identifier. I already try to make it but the position of triangle always in wrong position.

Here is the the code

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
shape = document.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "points", "5,0 25,0 15,15");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "black");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "black");
var x = sector.offset();
shape.setAttributeNS(null, 'x','xpos');
shape.setAttributeNS(null, 'y','Math.abs(ypos)');
shape.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');
//var draw = document.getElementById(sector.attr('id'))
$(svg).append(shape);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nanadia/9fsd3953/3/

Comment: Please reduce your sample to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of other stuff in your sampl that is not related to this question (eg. the mouseover code and the dropdown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using jQuery functions like `offset()`.  That gives the position of things in page coordinates. And I'm not even sure it works with SVG elements.

If you are inserting elements into the SVG, then you want to use SVG coordinates, not page coordinates.  You can find the location of elements in the SVG by getting the bounding box of SVG elements using the method `getBBox()`.

```js
$('polygon').click(function(evt) {

  // Find the group that contains the polygon that was clicked on
  var group = evt.target.parentNode;
  // Get the bounding box of the group
  var bbox = group.getBBox();
  // Add a triangle to the group
  var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  var shape = document.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");
  shape.setAttribute("points", "-10,0, 10,0, 0,15");   // triangle centered on x=0
  shape.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "black");
  var xPos = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;  // Horizontal centre of the bbox
  var yPos = bbox.y + bbox.height;     // Bottom of the group bbox
  shape.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + xPos + "," + yPos + ")");
  group.appendChild(shape);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="svgselect" style="width: 610px; height: 230px;">
      <!-- background-color:red -->
      <svg version="1.1" height="100%" width="100%">
        <g transform="scale(1.5)" id="gmain">
         
          <g id="P17" transform="translate(25,0)">
            <polygon points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  20,0  15,5  5,5" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="T" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="5,15   15,15   20,20   0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="B" opacity="1" class="B17"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,5   20,0  20,20   15,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="R" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  5,5   5,15  0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="L" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <text x="6" y="30" stroke="navy" fill="navy" stroke-width="0.1" style="font-size: 6pt;font-weight:normal">17</text>
          </g>
          <g id="P16" transform="translate(50,0)">
            <polygon points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  20,0  15,5  5,5" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="T" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="5,15   15,15   20,20   0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="B" opacity="1" class="B16"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,5   20,0  20,20   15,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="R" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  5,5   5,15  0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="L" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <text x="6" y="30" stroke="navy" fill="navy" stroke-width="0.1" style="font-size: 6pt;font-weight:normal">16</text>
          </g>
          <g id="P15" transform="translate(75,0)">
            <polygon points="5,5  15,5  15,15   5,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="C" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  20,0  15,5  5,5" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="T" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="5,15   15,15   20,20   0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="B" opacity="1" class="B15"></polygon>
            <polygon points="15,5   20,0  20,20   15,15" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="R" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <polygon points="0,0  5,5   5,15  0,20" fill="white" stroke="navy" stroke-width="0.5" id="L" opacity="1"></polygon>
            <text x="6" y="30" stroke="navy" fill="navy" stroke-width="0.1" style="font-size: 6pt;font-weight:normal">15</text>

          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>

  </div>
```